# How can I print the first value in a shuffled list?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to learn the idiomatic Haskell way to shuffle a list and take the first value off the head. I'm not even sure where in my program I should be doing this. So far, I've moved the logic to here:

```
-- {-# LANGUAGE UnicodeSyntax #-}
module RPS
    ( toss
    ) where

import System.Random.Shuffle
import Data.List

toss :: IO ()
toss =
    -- This doesn't actually work
    -- but I'd like to shuffle the list returned by
    -- getTosses and pull the first element out
    putStrLn "Biff tossed" ++ head shuffleM getTosses

getScissors :: [String]
getScissors =
    scissors where scissors = replicate 10 "✂️"

getPaper :: [String]
getPaper =
    paper where paper = replicate 10 ""

getRocks :: [String]
getRocks =
    rocks where rocks = replicate 10 ""

getPossibilities :: [String] -> [String] -> [String] -> [String]
getPossibilities rocks paper scissors =
    rocks ++ paper ++ scissors

getTosses :: [String]
getTosses =
    getPossibilities getRocks getPaper getScissors
```

While running this module in GHCi, I get

```
src/RPS.hs:11:36: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[[String] -> [a1]]’
                  with actual type ‘[a0] -> m0 [a0]’
    • Probable cause: ‘shuffleM’ is applied to too few arguments
      In the first argument of ‘head’, namely ‘shuffleM’
      In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘head shuffleM getTosses’
      In the expression:
```

The odd thing is, I can run `shuffleM getTosses` in GHCi just fine... it's only when I try to actually do that in a source file and then load that, that this fails. I've read that the shuffle monad only works in the context of IO, so I can't just shuffle a list in one of my other functions. I'm not sure if there's a better way.

Comment: First, `putStrLn` take only one argument. If you use `++`, makes sure to warp the argument. So, write it as `putStrLn (...)` or `putStrLn $ ...`. Second, just like `putStrLn`, `head` also take only one argument.

Comment: Don't forget that `head :: [a] -> a`. The String is a List of Char. If you take its head, it will be a Char.

Comment: `putStrLn ("Biff tossed" ++ head (shuffleM getTosses))` does give me a type error like you mention. What is the proper way to print a Char? Do I need to use `show`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
toss :: IO ()
toss = do
    shuffled <- shuffleM getTosses
    putStrLn $ "Biff tossed" ++ head shuffled
```

The main problem is that `shuffleM` has kind of type `MonadRandom m => [a] -> m [a]`. As you can see, `m` is a `MonadRandom`. You can't pass a wrapped value as *monad* directly to a pure function such as `head` since `head` has kind of type `[a] -> a`. We need to *unwrap* the `MonadRandom`. One of many ways to solve this is using `<-` keyword.

Comment: This works! So to understand better. You're using a block here, and using the `$` operator to ensure that the string concatenation is evaluated first. The fact that head of `shuffled` is a Char doesn't seem to be causing an issue though...

Comment: Thank you for that explanation!

Comment: I've edited the answer. Well, you are right. It seems the Char thing I've mentioned before not really a problem.